# Dynamic equivalent of these XML properties for a StackView

Tags: android, stackview

I am dynamically creating a `StackView` object in my Android project. How can I accomplish the following equivalent properties dynamically through code?

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:loopViews="true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the first:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setLayoutTransition

The second apparently has no related methods:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterViewAnimator.html#attr_android:loopViews

Answer (score 1):

For animateLayoutChanges you can refer [this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3aanimateLayoutChanges)

And for the loopViews i am not getting any method but you can refer [this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterViewAnimator.html#attr_android%3aloopViews)

Hope you got the Point. You can easilt search on developer site of Android for any other methods/function and its properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change loopViews, but you can try to pass it through constructor using styles.